# Parity preservation in set cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,Q$ be three sets such that $|A\cap Q|,|B\cap Q|$ are both even.
How can I prove that $|((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cap Q|$ is also even. All sets are finite.

Comment: |A| and |B| are finite ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=|A \cap Q|, b=|B \cap Q|, c=|A\cap B \cap Q|$. Then  $|((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cap Q|=a+b-2c$

Comment: Thanks for finding OP's misplaced espresso.